# Which is better for performance for sql row returns: inline vs function call

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a sql query that returns thousands of rows and this query is done on multiple pages. I was wondering if I could send the row returns individually to a function to build the return to make reusable code for maintainability. I know this could lead to overhead problems. Most likely the cap will be 5000 rows.

Will this compound on our server end with 10,000 users?

Any suggestions on a better way to do this?

```
Example: 

if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
  while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    array_push($data, returnFunction($row));
  }
}  

function returnFunction($row) {
  $dataTemp = new stdClass();
  $dataTemp->image = $row["image"];

  return $dataTemp;
}
```

Comment: In general, doing the work inside the database is the most efficient way to use databases.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: 10,000 user records might be inconsequential, or it might be gigabytes of data. It depends entirely on your schema, how you're loading it, and what you're doing with it, none of which is shown here.

Comment: i wouldn't worry about the overhead of _calling a function_. it's faaar outweighted by the better readability and reusability of the code. i'd rather worry about the memory footprint - do you need to have all 5000 rows in memory at the same time? also: stdClass basically has no benefits. either us the array you are getting, or define your classes properly.

Comment: Why not a function on your business rules layer doing that business rules stuff are supposed to do on a collection of data instead of an item of that collection? Let each layer do what they are supposed to do

Comment: I agree with the other comments that you should code for clarity, not micro-optimizations. PHP does have some overhead to calling a function, but it's small. If such small inefficiencies were important to you, you wouldn't be using PHP.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions! I did some testing and found the the difference was negligible, but also, using the array from the sql return is a great idea!